# AWS NotPrincipal in Resource Policy causes AccessDeniedException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Trying to restrict access to a SecretsManager secret and I am trying to attach this policy to the resource;

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:<account-id>:secret:1-Cc7SuZ",
            "NotPrincipal": {"AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/test-user2",
            "arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/test-admin"
        ]}
        },
    ]
}
```

and it throws this error;

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the PutResourcePolicy operation: User:
arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:user/test-admin is not authorized to perform: 
secretsmanager:PutResourcePolicy on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:<account-
id>:secret:1-Cc7SuZ with an explicit deny
```

For more context;

- Trying to attach a policy with the `Principal` instead of `NotPrincipal` works fine, so I don't understand how this can be a permission issue.
- The problem I am trying to solve involves a situation where all these users were already granted this access permission and I am only trying to have a few specified ones retain it.

As an aside, is there another way of solving this problem without having to revoke the earlier granted permission?

Comment: There is an **explicit deny**. Have to figure out where is it coming from. When you tested with `Principal` only, did you still have `Deny` in the policy?

Comment: Yes, I still had a deny. There's not explicit `Deny` anywhere else I created a fresh user and gave it admin permissions just to be sure.

Comment: I was checking [NotPrinciple](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_notprincipal.html) and aws recommends to look for other ways first, as using `NonPrinciple` can lead to some troubles.